# need to create a key with name Some Product(i.e. space between some and product )

Tags: file, batch-file, regedit

i need to create a key with name Some Product(i.e. space between some and product )

I tried following code and its giving error kindly look into it and provide your feedback

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Some Product 
reg add HKCU\Software\Some Product /v Version /t REG_SZ /d v2.4.6
```

Answer (score 2):

test also for errors:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Some Product" /v Version /t REG_SZ /d v2.4.6 >result.log 2>&1 && echo success || echo FAIL!
```

Messages and error messages are in `result.log`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote any parameter with spaces:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Some Product"  
reg add "HKCU\Software\Some Product" /v Version /t REG_SZ /d v2.4.6
```